# AngularJS + Test Anchor Element Click

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm creating some unit tests with Jasmine. I'm trying to understand how to test whether or not a link was clicked. For instance, I have the following written:

```
it('should click the link', inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
  var element = $compile('<a href="http://www.google.com" >Google.com</a>')($rootScope);
  $rootScope.$digest();

  expect(true).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Please note, I do NOT want to test if the browser window gets redirected to Google. The reason why is sometimes my links will redirect the user to a url. Sometimes they will trigger some JavaScript. Either way, I'm trying to test whether the link gets clicked or not. Eventually, I will be adding some behavior that ensures the default behavior of a link is skipped. With the idea of test-driven development in mind, I need to test to ensure that link clicks are currently being detected.

How do I test this in AngularJS with Jasmine?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would not be a AngularJS unit/integration test. It would be more like a end to end test.
If you want to write it the "Angular Way" you could write it like this:

In the view:

```
<p ng-click='redirectToGoogle()'>Google.com</p>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.redirectToGoogle = function(){
  $location.path('http://www.google.com');
};
```

And in your test:

```
describe('Redirect', function(){

  var location, scope, rootScope, controller;

  beforeEach(function(){
    inject(function ($injector){
      rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      scope = rootScope.$new();

      controller = $injector.get('$controller')("nameOfYourController", {$scope: scope});

      location = $injector.get('$location');
    });
  });

  it('should redirect to google', function){
    spyOn(location, 'path');

    scope.redirectToGoogle();

    expect(location.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://www.google.com');
  });

});
```